# T-SQL: 'where' query - multiple columns to match on

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working in SQL Server 2012. I know I can use there 'where' clause in a query to do a multi-variable search on a single column, eg.:

```
select * from cars where manufacturer in ('Ford', 'Toyota')
```

would return all rows that have Fort or Toyota as the manufacturer. However, what if I needed to be more specific, and I wanted to see cars made from Ford in 1995, and cars made in Toyota in 1996? Doing a query like this:

```
select * 
from cars 
where manufacturer in ('Ford', 'Toyota') 
  and year in ('1995', 1996)
```

would bring me back the data I needed, but also cars Toyota made in 1995, and cars Ford made in 1996, which I do not want in my dataset. I've seen some suggestions to do a query like this:

```
select * 
from cars 
where (manufacturer, year) in (('Ford', '1995'), ('Toyota', 1996))
```

However, this does not compile... I'm thinking this is a MySQL query. I would also like to be able to take the parameters for the where query from other tables, and not have to type in 'Ford', 'Toyota', '1995' every time I want to search

Comment: Why use `IN`instead of `AND`, `OR`? The last statement isn't standard SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
select * from cars 
where (manufacturer = 'Ford'   and year = '1995') 
   or (manufacturer = 'Toyota' and year = '1996')
```

Comment: That works for single queries, thanks! What if I had 100 (manufacturer + year) year combinations in a separate temp table? I liked using 'in' because I can run queries against it, but I am not seeing how I can make a subquery that would automatically return the combinations without me keying them in by hand

Comment: @user856358 If that was the case you should probably consider using a join instead and specify the predicate as the join condition instead of in the where clause.

Comment: I think I understand, so instead of doing a where query, do a table join on manufacturer in (a,b,c) and year in (x,y,z), and let the join do the filtering?

Comment: @user856358 Something like that; hard to say exactly how to do it without any sample data and desired results. Maybe you should post a new follow-up question if you want more precise suggestions.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about using joins to filter, I feel like this put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Just right the filter as you typed it in the question:

```
WHERE 
    (manufacturer='Ford' and year=1995) or 
    (manufacturer='Toyota' and year=1996)
```

There's no need to overcomplicate the WHERE statement. In fact, `where (manufacturer, year) in (('Ford', '1995'), ('Toyota', 1996))` isn't standared SQL